# Spring LDAP is reporting that password is wrong, but it isn't

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Have a Spring web app.  Had to change the password for the account with LDAP access.  Since then, it has given a password error for every user login.

Security config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http create-session="always" pattern="/**" disable-url-rewriting="true">
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/img/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/fonts/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/#/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticated" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/clusterMgrAuthenticated" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/getResearchData" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/admin/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/ui/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
       <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/#/login"/>
       <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint" /> 
       <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http> 

   <security:ldap-server url="ldap://ldap.us.org:389"
                   manager-dn="foo"
                   manager-password="bar"/>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider
                group-search-filter="(cn={0})"
                group-search-base="OU=Groups,OU=MCR,DC=mfad,DC=mfroot,DC=org"
                user-search-base="OU=Users,OU=MCR,DC=mfad,DC=mfroot,DC=org"
                user-search-filter="(cn={0})" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Have a different app with the same ldap settings, but security 4.2 instead of 3.2.  Its lookups work.

Comment: Have you enabled DEBUG logging of `org.springframework.security.ldap` package? What does it say when user tries to authenticate?

Comment: No @holmis83 I haven't. Is hat something I can do from the XML? Or does it need to be in my code?